# How to make animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to  slide the logo to right and again come from left
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZx90.png)
I tried this but it bounces back the logo

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
_controller = AnimationController(
 // duration: const Duration(seconds: 90),
  vsync: this,
)..repeat(reverse: false);
_offsetAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
  begin: Offset.zero,
  end: const Offset(7.1, 7.0),
).animate(CurvedAnimation(
  parent: _controller,
  curve: Curves.easeOutQuint,
));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code to slide the logo to right and again come from left,

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = AnimationController(
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    vsync: this,
  )..repeat(reverse: true);
  _offsetAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
    begin: Offset(-1.0,0.0),  // You can change starting position as per your require.
    end: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),  // You can change ending position as per your require.
  ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.linear,  // You can change animation curve per your require.
  ));
}
```

(Refer the [Curves class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves-class.html) to choose other curves).